# Android Gradle Warning Issue in signed apk. Please correct the above warnings first

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, warnings

What my issue is, When I generate signed apk am getting the Android gradle plugin Warnings. So am not able to generate the signed apk.
The warnings are showing in google gms dependencies.

I am using below in my gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 27
```

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

**Project gradle:**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

If I use 3.2.0 same warning issue only getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

Comment: Hi Padia, I copy paste your dependencies and compiled. Now am getting this error - **Java Compiler(1 error) "failed linking references".**